# how to load .xlsb in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, excel, uiwebview

is there any special way to load .xlsb (excel binary format) on UIwebview. I can load .xlsx as below but not .xlsb.

```
NSString  *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
path=[[path stringByAppendingString:@"/"]stringByAppendingString:@"myFile.xlsx"];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webPage loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, UIWebView does not support xlsb files, only xlsx files are supported. For further reference, Apple listed all supported document types here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1630/_index.html

Comment: thanks @Eike. Thats what i thought. I was looking if there is any other workaround or third party sdk to load .xlsb onto iOS. It does not have to be UIWebview.

Comment: There is a JavaScript based parser, but I have never used it in an ios webview: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

Comment: Just to make sure we do not miss the easy way: you can also migrate xlsb files to xlsx, so maybe this is an option too. It depends on where you get these files from, but it's an easy task on a server side.